# How to deploy redhat decision central on tomcat

Tags: drools, redhat, redhat-brms, redhat-bpm

I am new to Redhat and trying to deploy Redhat decision manager( decision central) V7.2 on tomcat server(v 8).As per online help I don't see any documentation to deploy decision central on tomcat. Please let me know if anyone has tried it before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Red Had Decision Manager is not supported for Tomcat. Only Kie Server can be used with Tomcat.

See [Red Hat Decision Manager 7 Supported Configurations](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3354301) and anchor [5] near different servers for more details.